# Website Needs to auto resize every element on the page like images and fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I've got a page that has a variety of text and images placed on the page.  When the users resizes their window (or users that simply have different resolutions), the design needs to have everything scale proportionally.  So I created this jQuery function that triggers on resize (or when page loads) and I look at every element I've put on that page so far and resize it based on the aspect ratio.
Like this:

```
    theWindow.resize(function() {
        resizeBg();
    }).trigger("resize");
```

As I add more and more to the page it is extremely tedious.  Every padding, margin, font-size, width, height, etc. needs to be resized based on that ratio.
Is there a jQuery plug-in or some other suggestion that would help with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually this behavior is achieved by using percentages/ems instead of using javascript to resize everything.

Comment: You can do this with just CSS in most cases. Think percentages rather than fixed-pixel amounts.

Comment: Use relative units to size everything and then just change the reference size.

Comment: Sometimes when things are hard it means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: read up on responsive design and start over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this, when a user resizes the window, JQuery runs a function.

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    var Width = $(document).width();
    var Height = $(document).height();

    $('body').css({"height" : Height, "width" : Width});
}
```

Or The easy way in CSS,

```
body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: and when you add other elements to the page just use the CSS above to set the width and height.

Comment: But its not just the width and height.  It is the padding, margin, font-size, etc.  The answers I've seen so far still require me to methodically set every value on a resize.  (I think).

Comment: Ok, so just use the css i gave you above for each thing